# Linq to Entities: complex query getting "average" restaurant rating

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity, linq-expressions

So I'm building a Restaurant Review site for my community.  I need to
extract data from the following tables:  RESTAURANT, CUISINE, CITY,
PRICE and RATING (customer ratings).

The query should return all restuarants of a selected CUISINE_ID and
return the RESTAURANT_NAME, CUSINE_NAME, CUTY_NAME, PRICE_CODE and it
should average all the reviews RATING_CODE and return a calculated
value.  I'm fine with returning all the data except the average
rating.

I've only been working with LINQ to Entities 2 days and LINQ for about
3 weeks, so I'm really a newbie; I'm waiting for my LINQ book to be
delivered from Amazon.com.  Your help guidance be appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to get some composite result that contains: RESTAURANT_NAME, CUSINE_NAME, CUTY_NAME, PRICE_CODE, and RATING_CODE_AVG?  Or is being able to generate the average code as a separate result from the rest of the data sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should end up looking something like this:

```
var avgForMatches = 
    (from r in context.Restaurants
     where r.Cuisines.Any(c => c.CuisineName == cuisineName)
     where r.Prices.Any(p => p.PriceCode == priceCode)
     //... same pattern for other searches.
     select r.RatingCode)
    .Average();
```

Comment: wow .... that is so simple.  One more question, 'context' ... is that a reserved word or does that refer to my entities model?

Comment: Yes, it is simple. Be warned: LINQ can get really addictive. ;-)  `context` is just the variable that refers to your entity model instance. I usually wrap EF query code in something like `using (var context = new MyEntityContext()) {...}`. (Actually, I usually use an injected factory, rather than creating it myself, but you get the general idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Read about aggregate methods (including average) within the 101 linq samples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747